# Django template regorup

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to regroup this on the basis of ingredients.
this is my sample result which I want
Just like the below picture as there is more than one certificate so I am showing them in one row.

[image]

Ingredient_name, **all the `stop_name` associated with that ingredient**,
**all  the `stop_longitude` associated with that ingredient** and so on in one table row.

Right now its showing like this and you can see that the ingredient name is repeating .
[image]

model

```
class SupplyChainStops(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    stop_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    stop_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    stop_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    is_supplier = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.stop_name}'
```

query

```
items = SupplyChainStops.objects.all()
```

template

```
        {% for item in items %}
            <tr class="text-black">
                <td>{{ item.ingredient }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.stop_name }}
                <td>{{ item.stop_longitude }}
                <td>{{ item.stop_latitude }}
```

This is my DB structure

[image]

This is my desired output
[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve. Would you elaborate and post the request.

Comment: @SivaSankar I want to group data on the basis of ingredient, in my DB I have more than one stop name, stop longitude and stop latitude associated with one ingredient. So I want to display data in such a way that all the stop names etc should come in one row of that ingredient

Comment: @SivaSankar i have added a reference picture

Comment: is the stop_name, stop_longitude and stop_latitude unique. I mean the combination of these 3 is unique?

Comment: yes they are unique

Comment: @SivaSankar i have also added the DB values for the reference

Comment: can you change the db structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241830/discussion-between-the-knight-and-siva-sankar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `related_name` for `ForeignKey` field.

```
class SupplyChainStops(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="supply_chain_stops")
```

in view:

```
each_row = []
ing_ids = []
sup = SupplyChainStops.objects.all()
for each_sup in sup:
    ing_ids.append(each_sup.ingredient.id)
ing_ids = list(set(ing_ids))
sch = []
for each_ing_id in ing_ids:
    sch.append(SupplyChainStops.objects.filter(ingredient__id= each_ing_id).last())

for each in sch:
    stop_names_list = []
    stop_longitude_list = []
    stop_latitude_list = []
    mi_list = each.ingredient.supply_chain_stops.all()
    for each_mi in mi_list:
        stop_names_list.append(each_mi.stop_name)
        stop_longitude_list.append(each_mi.stop_longitude)
        stop_latitude_list.append(each_mi.stop_latitude)
    row_list = [each.ingredient, stop_names_list, stop_longitude_list, stop_latitude_list]
    each_row.append(row_list)
context = { 
"items": each_row 
}
```

in template:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr class="text-black">
        <td>{{ item.0 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.1|join:", " }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.2|join:", " }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.3|join:", " }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: its showing nothing.

Comment: did you send the ingredients to template from the view

Comment: can you come to the same chat room?

Comment: i have updated my OP with a picture of my desired output